# Wordpress Search Results for Multiple Post Types

Tags: php, loop, search, attachments

I want to show both `posts` and `attachments` in the search results. Basically, I need something that says `if` the post has a thumbnail, show it. `else` show the attachment image (since they don't have thumbnails and are being pulled directly from the media library).

This is what I've tried on`search.php`, but it didn't work:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php
            echo '<a class="search-item">';
            if( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                $image_src = the_post_thumbnail( 'custom-size', array( 'class' => "img-style" ) );
            }
            else {
                $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( 'custom-size', array( 'class' => "img-style" ) );
                echo '</a>';
            }
        ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) function expects you to also pass some kind of attachment ID plus it doesn't grab the image HTML that we need so instead we should use [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/).

**IF** a post has a post thumbnail, grab it.
**ELSE IF** the post has any attached images, grab the first one.
**ELSE** maybe show a placeholder? I've defined the else case at the top of the loop as a default.

```
if( have_posts() ) {
    while( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        $image_html = ''; // assign placeholder url here?

        if( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            $image_html = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'custom-size', array( 'class' => 'img-style' ) );
        } else { // We don't have a thumbnail - grab attachments
            $media = get_posts( array(
                'post_type'         => 'attachment',
                'posts_per_page'    => 1,
                'post_status'       => 'any',
                'post_parent'       => $post->ID
                'post_mime_type'    => array( 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/bmp', 'image/tiff', 'image/x-icon' );
            ) );

            if( ! empty( $media ) ) {
                $image_html = wp_get_attachment_image( $media[0]->ID, 'cusotm-size', false, array( 'class' => 'img-style' ) );
            }
        }

        if( ! empty( $image_html ) ) {
            echo '<a href="'. get_permalink() . '">' . $image_html . '</a>';
        }
    }
}
```

Note, I haven't tested the above so feel free to refine it.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly the right direction I needed to go. My final code looks lie this: `if(has_post_thumbnail()) {                    
the_post_thumbnail( 'custom-size', array( 'class' => "img-style" ) );
echo '</a>';}
else {
    echo '<img class="img-style" src="'.wp_get_attachment_url ().'"/>';    
    }?>  
<?php
 //End the post loop
 endwhile; else:
?> `